# Use a classes properties as options for a methods parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class called `Snackbar` which has properties and methods within it like this:

```js
export class SnackbarComponent {
  optionA: number;
  option2: string;

  method1(){}
}
```

I would like to add the `properties` as keys in the options. I am using `[I in SnackbarComponent]: SnackbarComponent[I];` but it is giving me the following errors:

> - A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
> - A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
> - Cannot find name 'I'.ts(2304)
> - Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)

```js
export class SnackbarService {
  show(message: string, options?: {
    randomString: string;
    [I in SnackbarComponent]: SnackbarComponent[I];
  }): Snackbar {
    // Create instance of SnackbarComponent
    // Set the properties on the SnackbarComponent
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a `keyof`

```
export class SnackbarService {
  show(message: string, options?: {
    [K in keyof SnackbarComponent]: SnackbarComponent[K]
  })
```

Comment: An additional error was that I needed to use a union. so `{[K in keyof SnackbarComponent]: SnackbarComponent[K]} & {otherProperty: string}`

Comment: Also, is there a way to filter out functions from the options without using `Omit`/`Exclude`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I think you need to write helper anyways to effectively do an Omit etc. Let me know if you find otherwise. Following